# How to get QgsFeatureRequest in a virtual Layer?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, virtual-layer

I am wondering if/how PyQGIS can intercept the `QgsVirtualLayerProvider::getFeatures()` requests of a VirtualLayer, and pull out just the spatial extent from the `QgsFeatureRequest` to dynamically formulate a subselect for one piece of a query, to be used as an 'IN' clause of a larger, more complex query ...

I effectively want to select polygon ids from one spatial layer, and use their ids on the fly to select features from another, much larger time series table. Simply making a view joining the two by id doesn't work: for every polygon id, there may be hundreds of rows.

So I want to explicitly pick apart the `QgsFeatureRequest` into spatial vs attribute components, and execute well-crafted queries appropriately.

I want to be issuing queries to PostGIS that look something like:

```
select b.price, b.block_id, g.the_geom from hc_models.block_ts b, join tiger_latest.tabblock g on b.block_id = g.tabblock_id
where b.month = ‘2005-01-01’ and b.block_id in

(select tabblock_id from tiger_latest.tabblock WHERE "the_geom" && st_makeenvelope(-122.45845691920965237,37.75162120370001873,-122.44739741920977849,37.75793370369994761,4269)
```

the subselect against `tiger_latest.tabblock` will yield a few dozen rows, and the subsequent query against `hc_models.block_ts` will hit a combined month+id index.

Can this be done in a Virtual Layer? I see a tantalizing comment in the "Index Support" description for Virtual Layers:

> "For spatial indexes, a 'hidden' field named 'search_frame' is created
>   for each virtual table (i.e. each referenced layer of the virtual
>   layer). The bounding box of the given geometry will be used to
>   restrain the query to a particular region of space. This bounding box
>   is passed to the underlyng provider by a QgsFeatureRequest with a
>   "filterRect".

How to use this?  Or should I just bite the bullet and start with a raw QgsPluginLayer?

Comment: still struggling with this ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your purpose but I recommand you to head to the Python unit tests for `QgsVirtualLayerProvider`.

There are several cases to explore using VirtualLayers with `QgsFeatureRequest`. You can see them at [QGis Github code repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/final-2_18_3/tests/src/python/test_provider_virtual.py) (PS: I link to QGIS 2.18 series code)